# CPU usage of running procedure from SSMS VS scheduled job

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL procedure that loops through ~326000 entries in a table with a cursor, calculates times based on these entries and inserts the result for each entry in another table.
If I run this procedure from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio it runs through without an issue.
I want the procedure to run every sunday to monday night. So I created a scheduled job for it.
If the job runs it takes 100% of the CPU usage. I tried to use [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69697/set-maximum-cpu-usage-to-a-single-job-in-sql-server) to cap the maximum CPU usage but it didn't work.

My procedure is called Player Stats.

```
CREATE RESOURCE POOL Pool_PlayerStats WITH
(
    max_cpu_percent=10, 
    cap_cpu_percent=10 -- 2012+ only 
);
GO

CREATE WORKLOAD GROUP Group_PlayerStats
  USING Pool_PlayerStats;
GO

ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RGClassifier()
RETURNS SYSNAME
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT CASE ORIGINAL_LOGIN() WHEN N'Player Stats'
    THEN N'Group_PlayerStats' ELSE N'default' END);
END
GO

ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR WITH (CLASSIFIER_FUNCTION = dbo.RGClassifier);
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

I added the function dbo.RGClassifier to the master-database while the scheduled job should run on another database. Was that correct?

Why is it that with SSMS I don't have any issues but with a scheduled job I do? How can I fix this?

Edit:

As asked here is the procedure:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @PlayerId INT,
  @GameMinutes INT,
  @SumGames INT,
  @SumAfk INT

DECLARE  C CURSOR LOCAL FOR SELECT ID FROM PLAYER  WITH (NOLOCK)

DELETE FROM dbo.PlayerStatistics

OPEN C

FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @PlayerId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

 select @GameMinutes=COALESCE(sum(a.Diff), 0) from
 (select DATEDIFF(Minute, Game.TimeStarted, Game.TimeEnded) Diff from Player join GamePlayer on Player.Id = GamePlayer.PlayerId
 join Game on Game.Id = GamePlayer.GameId
 where Player.Id = @PlayerId
 and TimeEnded >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
 ) a

 select @SumAfk=COALESCE(sum(a.Diff), 0) from 
 (
  select DATEDIFF(Minute, Game.TimeStarted, Game.TimeEnded) Diff from Player join GamePlayer on Player.Id = GamePlayer.PlayerId
  join Game on Game.Id = GamePlayer.GameId
  join GameKill on GameKill.GameId = GamePlayer.GameId
  where Player.Id = @PlayerId
  and GameKill.KillMethodId In (9, 17)
  and GameKill.VictimId = @PlayerId
  and TimeEnded >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
 ) a

 select @SumGames=COALESCE(count(*), 0) from GamePlayer join GameKill on GamePlayer.GameId = GameKill.GameId
 where GameKill.KillMethodId NOT IN (1, 9, 17)
 and GamePlayer.PlayerId = @PlayerId
 and GameKill.TimeStamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
 and GameKill.VictimId = @PlayerId

 SET @GameMinutes = @GameMinutes - @SumAfk

 IF (@GameMinutes < 0)
 BEGIN
  SET @GAMEMINUTES = 0
 END

 insert into dbo.PlayerStatistics(PlayerId, GameCount, InGameMinutes)
 values (@PlayerId, @SumGames, @GameMinutes)

 -- set the donation level

 IF (@GameMinutes < 360)
 BEGIN
  update Player set DonationLevel = 0 where Id = @PlayerId
 END

 IF (@GameMinutes >= 360)
 BEGIN
  update Player set DonationLevel = 10 where Id = @PlayerId
 END

 IF (@GameMinutes >= 600)
 BEGIN
  update Player set DonationLevel = 50 where Id = @PlayerId
 END

 IF (@GameMinutes >= 840)
 BEGIN
  update Player set DonationLevel = 100 where Id = @PlayerId
 END

 FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @PlayerId

END

END
```

The job logs in as the administrator of the PC. Should I change the function dbo.RGClassifier() to PCNAME\Administrator?

Comment: I'm dying to see this procedure like an itch I want to scratch. Just to confirm `Player Stats' is the login being used by the job?

Comment: @JNevill actually that was the error. Thanks.

Comment: Rockin! I'm glad that did the trick :)

Comment: @JNevill nvm it didn't do the trick. I didn't wait until the end of the run through the job.

Comment: When you say "scheduled job" do you mean an SQL Agent job, or are you using Windows Scheduled Tasks? If the latter, what are you executing the SQL with? In all likelihood it's using a different set of connection @@OPTIONS values between SSMS and whatever's executing your proc causing a bad execution plan to be created and run.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning its an SQL Agent Scheduled job. How do I check the settings/options for the connection the job uses? I don't even know how to set the connection. I just went with the default the job offered.

Comment: I don't think Agent gives you the ability to set connection options (in the GUI). As a starting point you can create a job that executes `PRINT @@OPTIONS;`, run it and check the job log for the result, then execute `PRINT @@OPTIONS` in SSMS and compare the two. Armed with the two values gives you two options: (1) tweak options in SSMS to match Agent then you can start looking at execution plans to figure out why performance is going haywire and fix it, or (2)  add a series of `SET <OPTION> <ON|OFF>;` statements to the job agent SQL to match SSMS before executing your stored procedure.

Comment: See the [@@OPTIONS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/options-transact-sql) reference as well as various pages on the internet that document the bitmask and how it relates to the named options.